# File structure for application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently developing an application as a CMS. I will be using it to display content on my main page. I'm using Codeigniter to develop this application and wanted to know what is the ideal file structure for my application. I've researched and found many different ways but they all have their purposes and strengths and flaws and want to know what is really the best accepted way.

As of right now my thinking was to do the following file structure.

```
/application
            /frontend
            /backend
/models
       /frontend
       /backend
/views
      /frontend
      /backend
```

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any standardized structure, so it's really down to you to decide. The one you chose is great

Comment: What is the strength and flaws of your structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really one best way to structure your files, it really is what works best for you. I developed a framework using a true MVC file structure, but over time working with my frontend developer the structure changed drastically to suit his and my needs/preferences. Start with what you have now, then as you use it more and more you will come to see what you do and don't like. Then, re-make it from scratch. It took me many rebuilds to finally get the structure that I wanted, but now that I have it I am 10 times more efficient. Every developer is different, and what works for someone else may not work well for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed structure looks OK to me. Everyone has their own idea of what makes a "good" file organization scheme. There's not really a "best accepted" way to do it. As long as you keep it logical and simple, and do your best to make sure your folder structure isn't going to get in your own way during development, you're fine.